# Getting an error about not having an Identifier even when I have one

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

This is my UserRole class. Here, the id_roles, id_users and updated_by are supposed to be foreign keys (id_roles coming from the Role table and the other two coming from the User table, I'll put the code for each one of the tables down below)

```
package offgrid.models;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRolePK UserRolePK;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_roles", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Role roleId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_users", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User userId;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "update_by", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private User updatedBy;

    public offgrid.models.UserRolePK getUserRolePK() {
        return UserRolePK;
    }

    public void setUserRolePK(offgrid.models.UserRolePK userRolePK) {
        UserRolePK = userRolePK;
    }

    public Role getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Role roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public User getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(User userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public User getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(User updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
}
```

And this is my UserRolePK

```
package offgrid.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Long roleId;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(Long roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserRolePK that = (UserRolePK) o;
        return userId.equals(that.userId) && roleId.equals(that.roleId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, roleId);
    }
}
```

Here is my User class

```
package offgrid.models;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    private String photo;

    @Column(name = "tax_id")
    private String taxId;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updateAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by")
    private User user;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getTaxId() {
        return taxId;
    }

    public void setTaxId(String taxId) {
        this.taxId = taxId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdateAt() {
        return updateAt;
    }

    public void setUpdateAt(LocalDateTime updateAt) {
        this.updateAt = updateAt;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And the Role class

```
package offgrid.models;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "updated_by")
    private User updatedBy;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public User getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(User updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run my code:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: offgrid.models.UserRole

But as I detailed above, there I put an EmbeddedId annotation referencing my UserRolePK class.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
```

But you used annotations on fields.
Change it to:

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
```

or remove it, as JPA know it is FIELD base on where you placed the annotations.